# Old Electric Symbol Puzzle

Tags: circuit-design, symbol

Here is a weird puzzle.

What old electrical symbols are these two?

They could be standard but also proprietary: i.e. two symbols superimposed to indicate a multiple function before ANSI and IEC standardized.

[image]

It's either IEC variable resistor or a thermistor, with something else underneath?

Is this some pre 1950 German standard?
i.e. "Handbuch der Funktechnik und ihrer Grenzgebiete, Bd. 9; Fortschritte der Funktechnik, Bd. 6, Franckh, Stuttgart, 1941"

[image]

Maybe "Intermediate switch"? but I could be wrong.

Comment: Some context might help here. Where did you find these symbols?

Comment: "Not suitable for cooking hamburgers" and "You have email" would be my guess.